# A word to describe dislike caused by not knowing a person

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Is there a word to describe the negative emotion you can feel for an individual you barely know, and the things you dislike about them have largely/entirely been invented in your head *over a long period*?

For example:

> Jane had never spoken to Bob before, but after 2 years, she had strong
> feelings of `X` towards him. This most likely began when he bumped into her
> in the office lift. As with many cases of `X`, the two have barely exchanged a word in their lives.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to: Ram Pillai

**Bias**

> unreasonably hostile feelings or opinions about a social group; prejudice.

Source: [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bias)

Some examples:

1. There are tons of online disputes as to Wikipedia's reliability, accuracy, **and lack of bias**.
2. Reporters must be impartial and **not show political bias**.

Or:

**Preconceived notion**

> noun – An opinion formed beforehand without adequate evidence.

Source: [thesaurus](https://thesaurus.plus/related/assumption/preconceived_notion#:%7E:text=Preconceived%20notion%20noun%20%E2%80%93%20An%20opinion,noun%20phrase%20%22Preconceived%20notion%22)

Some examples:

1. her perception of him was dwarfed because of her own **preconceived notion** of him.
2. she had a bad impression of him based on a **preconceived notion**

Comment: Bias...? Bias may be against or in favour of... ;)

Comment: I think bias is pretty much what the author is looking for

Comment: Negative bias doesn't imply a lack of communication. I can have a negative bias towards my wife, whom I speak with every day. However, I'd like a word to describe the negative bias that grows only through not speaking to someone.